# Derivation of properties of determinants from few basics assumptions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am reading the book Methods of Applied Mathematics by Hildebrand and in one of the footnotes (pg. 10, section 1.2, second edition), the author mentions, "If we impose the conditions,

1. if all the elements of one row (or one column) of a square matrix are multiplied by a number k, the the determinant is multiplied by k,
2. If to the elements of any row (column) are added k times the corresponding elements of any other row (column), the determinant is unchanged,
3. The determinant is unity when the diagonal elements are unity and and all other elements are zero,

then the following condition will hold:

The value of the determinant will be unchanged if the row and columns of the matrix are unchanged.

Can someone point me to a reference or give a hint on how this was arrived at?

Comment: This will be covered in any Linear Algebra textbook that starts with the definition of a vector space. I qualify this because there are some textbooks on Linear Algebra that start with systems of linear equations and are more computational than theoretical.

Comment: Do you happen to know a linear algebra book like that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696716/textbooks-in-which-determinant-is-defined-as-an-alternating-multilinear-map